# How change screen dynamically using Drawer Navigator

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer

I have a Drawer Navigator with 2 screens, Home and Profile. What I need is, when I click in a TouchaleOpacity, change the screen from home to profile, how can I do this?

```
import { DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import JsHome from './JsHome'
import JsProfile from './JsProfile'

const DrawerExample = DrawerNavigator({
  JsHome : {
    screen: JsHome 
  },

  JsProfile : {
    screen: JsProfile 
  },
}
```

PS: the TouchableOpacity are in another js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

each screen has navigation props. use this.props.navigation.navigate('JsProfile') in your touchable opacity